# A property on the unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis, spheres

I found this lemma in:  *[Furi, M., Vignoli, A.: On a property of the unit sphere in a linear normed space. Bull. Pol.
Acad. Sci. Math. 18, 333–334 (1970)]*

> Lemma:
>   Let $S^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere of the real Euclidean space $E^n$.
>   Let $\{A_1, A_2, ..., A_q\}$ be a finite family of closed sets with the following two properties:
>
> a) $\cup_{k=1}^q  A_k =S^{n-1}$;
>
> b)None of the sets $A_k (k= 1, 2, ..., q)$ contains two symmetric (with respect to the origin) points, then
>
> $q>n$

Do you have any idea of the proof?

Comment: have you tried by induction? It seems something quite easy to prove by that, but not that easy without it, just as first impression

Comment: Does the source not give a proof or a reference to one?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen They gived a reference - very old ref -  which I didn't find in the net

Comment: @Oscar induction on n?

Comment: I think the inequality on $q$ must be the other way, more precisely under the conditions stated in the question, the conclusion must be that $q\leq n$. The latter is the statement of Lyusternik-Shnirel’man lemma (just google it for details, it's a non-trivial result) which states that if you cover the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by at least $n+1$ closed sets, then at least one of these sets must contain a pair of antipodal points. In your case, you stated the counter-positive of the Lemma.

Comment: @Hayk  No! $q>n$, and what you said : " if you cover the unit sphere of $\mathbb R^n$ by at least $n+1$ closed sets, then at least one of these sets must contain a pair of antipodal points" is exactly what the lemma claims

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to prove the equivalent statement that if $q\leq n$ then at least one of $A_i$ contains antipodal points.

Consider the case when $q=n$ and assume that $A_{n}$ (the last closed subset) doesn't have antipodal points. If it has then we are obviously done. Consider function

$$f:S^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$$
$$f(v)_i=d(v, A_i)$$

where $d(v,A_i)$ is the distance of $v$ from $A_i$. Note that this doesn't include the last subset. This is well defined and continuous map. By the Borsuk-Ulam theorem there is $v\in S^{n-1}$ such that $f(v)=f(-v)$. But since $\{A_i\}$ cover whole $S^{n-1}$ then $v\in A_j$ for some $j$.

Now if $j<n$ then $f(v)_j=0=f(-v)_j$, i.e. $d(v,A_j)=d(-v, A_j)=0$. Because each $A_i$ is closed then $-v\in A_j$.

On the other hand if $j=n$ then we can consider $-v$. Since $A_n$ doesn't contain antipodals then $-v\in A_k$ for some $k<n$ and thus previous "$j<n$" case applies to $-v$ and $A_k$.

Therefore for $q=n$ at least one of $A_i$ contains antipodal points. $\Box$

The case when $q<n$ you solve by artifically adding singletons to $\{A_1,\ldots, A_q\}$ and going back to $q=n$. Note that singletons cannot contain antipodal points.

All in all: if $q\leq n$ then at least one of $A_j$ contains anitpodal points. Or equivalently: if none of $A_j$ contains anitpodal points then $q>n$.

Of course the hard part of the solution is [the Borsuk-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) which is far from trivial.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but Lusternik–Schnirelmann says that if the number of covering (closed) sets goes beyond the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then at least one of the sets must contain a pair of antipodal points. While in the statement of the problem, part (b), we have that no member of the covering family contains a pair $(x,-x)$. So, that means that we should have $q\leq n$, rather than the opposite.

Comment: @Hayk That's not what Lusternik–Schnirelmann says. Have a look at $S^1$ and cover it with $4$ closed subsets: each being an arc of angle $\pi/2$.

Comment: ah yes, of course. Thanks for the example (+1).